# Using RAM XMP with 4 Sticks of RAM

Tags: memory, bios, overclocking

I always had 2 RAM Sticks installed, both with 8GB Capacity and 3000Mhz, which did work perfectly fine with A-XMP activated.

I now installed 2 more RAM Sticks (exactly the same size, brand and MHz-Rate), which I can use at 2133Mhz. But when I activate A-XMP and restart, i cant get my PC to boot properly.

The CPU Fan is spinning very hard and loud, and also my CPU-Debug-Lamp is activated.

Can someone tell me, where the problem is?

I already tried overwriting the Voltages to 1.4 V and 1.1 V, but that doesn’t seem to do the trick and I really dont want to get higher than that!

I really dont understand, why OC works with 2 Sticks, but not with 4. But maybe there is some reason, I really dont am a professional in this area.

Specs:

- **MAINBOARD**: MSI B450 PRO-VHD-MAX
- **BIOS**: newest version from 18.03.2022
- **MEMORY**: DDR4, 4x8 GB, each with 3000Mhz, 2x16GB DIMM Kits from G.Skill
- **CPU**: AMD Ryzen 5 3600

Comment: In your PC the memory controller is part of the CPU.  With 4 DIMMs installed it has to work 'harder' (sorry, not really a technical explanation). So it is quite normal that more installed memory modules means a lower OC potential.  So that sense is nothing 'wrong'.

Answer (score 1):

The
[B450M PRO-VDH MAX manual](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B450M-PRO-VDH-MAX/support#manual)
has this about memory:

[image]

It seems that you are not really using an A-XMP configuration,
which would have made available more performant modes.

I suggest instead of accepting the profile suggested by default,
to click "Memory Try It !".
This will give you a list of commonly used memory timings and frequencies.
Try setting one that sits just below your memory’s rated speed until
you find one that is stable.

For more information see the article
[Guide to XMP Memory Profiles – How to set XMP Profiles in your BIOS](https://www.cgdirector.com/xmp-memory-profile-guide/)
and especially the section "How to Set XMP in MSI BIOS".

The following images were taken from the article:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for your detailed answer. Will be the first thing in the morning I try!